# PIL: OSError: Unknown File Format

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, urllib

Attempted to use a piece of code from other questions on Stack Overflow. Ran into this piece of code:

```
from PIL import ImageFont
from urllib.request import urlopen

truetype_url = 'https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/main/src/hinted/Roboto-Black.ttf'
font = ImageFont.truetype(urlopen(truetype_url), size=10)
```

I got this error:

```
OSError: unknown file format
```

I tried other suggestions such as reinstalling PIL, using requests.get and I receive the same error. I checked the link and it does take you to the item in question. Are there other suggestions I can try?

My Goal:
Be able to take a font from a link so I do not have to do this locally on my computer.

Thanks!

Comment: When I visit that URL - because it's on GitHub - I don't get the TTF file; I get a web page wrapper. Try adding `?raw=true` to the URL.

Comment: Hmmm.. that didn't seem to work. I know when you select the 'view raw' portion in github, it pops open a file where i can print or install the item. Do not quite know what that means in this case.

Comment: I could be asking the wrong question though. I am trying to create an image and will eventually use Heroku to run the script. So my goal was to see if there was a way to use a link to attain the font because i cannot really write things without a font of some sort i believe.

Comment: Okay, so, I told you how to change the URL in order to "use a link to attain the font". You've been given an answer now that uses that changed URL, and is apparently successful. You say that when you tried it, it "didn't seem to work"; but I neither know what exactly you changed, or how the resulting behaviour is different from what you wanted to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import requests
import io

# Load font from URI
truetype_url = 'https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/main/src/hinted/Roboto-Black.ttf?raw=true'
r = requests.get(truetype_url, allow_redirects=True)
font = ImageFont.truetype(io.BytesIO(r.content), size=24)

# Create a black canvas and get drawing context
canvas = Image.new('RGB', (300,180))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)

# Write in our font
draw.text((10, 10), "Got that crazy font", font=font, fill=(255,255,255))
canvas.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

As Karl points out in the comments, you can do it with `urllib` as you were originally intending like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

truetype_url = 'https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/main/src/hinted/Roboto-Black.ttf?raw=true'

font = ImageFont.truetype(urlopen(truetype_url), size=10)
```

Comment: I would have to do work to set up a proper test for myself, but... is `requests` actually necessary for this? Isn't the `HTTPResponse` from the built-in `urllib.request.urlopen` sufficiently file-like?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just tried it, and yes, it does work. I only did it with `requests` because OP said it didn't work in a comment and because I believe it to be more modern and popular. I will add it into the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you for the help and my apologies Karl. For some reason, I had replaced Main with Master in my URL. So when I put in ?raw=true, it was giving me the same error. I had not noticed that I changed that when I was playing around with other links. Thank you Mark for your answer. It works like a charm.