# How I can load a font file with PIL.ImageFont.truetype in replit

Tags: discord.py, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make this welcome card thingy in discord.py and I'm running my bot on replit.com as of now.

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 28)
```

I got some examples and it worked great as long as I'm running it on my PC but wen I get to replit.com it gives the error saying

```
Command raised an exception: OSError: cannot open resource
```

How should I go about correcting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `discord` or `replit` but presume the issue is that you can't upload your binary font file.

If so, you have a couple of options:

- find your desired font online somewhere and use `requests.get(URL)` to grab it in your code on `replit`, or
- make a base64 variable in your code and decode it

The first option is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66999827/2836621).

Let's look at the second. Say your font is called `/Fonts/funky.ttf` on your PC. Now you want that in base64 which you can do with a commandline tool on your local PC:

```
base64 < /Fonts/funky.txt
```

That will make a long string of characters. Copy it, and in your Python code add a string called `font64` and set it equal to the pasted string, i.e.

```
font64 = 'PASTED STRING'
```

Now in your code you can convert the string back from base64 to binary, then wrap it in a BytesIO to make it look like a file and load it:

```
import base64
import io
from PIL import ImageFont

font64 = 'PASTED STRING'

# decode from base64 to binary
binary = base64.b64decode(font64)

# wrap in BytesIO to make file-like object
FileLike = io.BytesIO(binary)

# load font
font = ImageFont.truetype(FileLike, 28)
```

Comment: THANKS A LOOT MANZ! the first option worked sweet fomme