# Pillow truetype not working with py-script

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyscript

I'm wanting to be able to add an image and then have it add some text to it but it's not working. I have started where the error is happening. It's with the truetype function of the ImageFont class. If you could tell me why this is happening and how to fix the error if there is a way to fix it all. the truetype was introduced into pillow in version 4.2.0 and according to PYODIDE it has version 9.1.1 so I would expect it to work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
<py-config type="json">
  {
    "autoclose_loader": true,
    "runtimes": [{
        "src": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.2/full/pyodide.js",
        "name": "pyodide-0.21.3",
        "lang": "python"
    }],
    "fetch": [{
      "packages": ["Pillow"]
    }]
  }
</py-config>
<py-env>
    - Pillow
</py-env>
<label for="Upload a PNG image"></label><input type="file" id="file-upload-pillow">
<div id="output_upload_pillow"></div>
<py-script>
from js import document, console, Uint8Array, window, File
from pyodide.ffi import create_proxy
import io

from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageFont, ImageDraw

async def _upload_change_and_show(e):
    file_list = e.target.files
    first_item = file_list.item(0)

    array_buf = Uint8Array.new(await first_item.arrayBuffer())

    bytes_list = bytearray(array_buf)
    my_bytes = io.BytesIO(bytes_list) 

    my_image = Image.open(my_bytes)

    console.log(f"{my_image.format= } {my_image.width= } {my_image.height= }")


    *font = ImageFont.truetype(font="text-font/Roboto-Black.ttf", size=20)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
    draw.text((0, 0),"Sample Text",(255,255,255), font=font)

    my_stream = io.BytesIO()
    my_image.save(my_stream, format="PNG")


    image_file = File.new([Uint8Array.new(my_stream.getvalue())], "new_image_file.png", {type: "image/png"})

    new_image = document.createElement('img')
    new_image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(image_file)
    document.getElementById("output_upload_pillow").appendChild(new_image)

   
upload_file = create_proxy(_upload_change_and_show)
document.getElementById("file-upload-pillow").addEventListener("change", upload_file)
</py-script>
```

Comment: Open the browser debugger. Are there any warnings/errors on the Console or Network tabs?

Comment: Why `*font`? And where is the TrueType font file supposed to be loaded from? Somewhere on the browser's filesystem or somewhere on the server's filesystem? Sorry I don't know PyScript. Maybe you need to grab the font some other way https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169500/2836621 As I said, I am completely unfamiliar with PyScript and my suggestions may be bad practice or plain wrong.

Comment: Hello? Any progress on this please?

Comment: Sorry I figured it out, it was something with I wasn't hosting it on like a webserver I got help from the discord (https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/257#issuecomment-1119595062)